# C Programming - fgets() infinite while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets, file-read

I am having an issue with taking in an augmented matrix from a text file. The program will simply segfault after successfully reading in all of the data from the text file, most likely because it is still looking for another token to reach or fgets() isn't reaching a NULL state? I'm honestly lost...

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include "apmatrix.h"
#define NUMARGS 2 
#define BUFSIZE 128

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    /* Matrices that will always be used */
    Matrix* A;
    Vector* b;
    Vector* x;
    iVector* p;

    /* Used in LU factorization */
    Matrix* L;
    Matrix* U;

    /* Standard character read-in variables needed */
    char sep[] = " "; /* parsing separator is space */
    char *z,*buffer;  /* buffer and pointer to scan buffer */
    FILE *ifp;        /* source file */ 
    unsigned buflen;  /* length of line read */
    int flag, count;
    int Rows,Columns;/* to hold number read */
    int CurrentRow=0;

    /* first check to see if have required number for argc */ 
    /* if not, error has occurred, don't do anything else */ 
    if (argc == 2 || argc==3) 
    { 
        /* correct number of arguments used, try to open both files */ 
        buffer = (char*) malloc(BUFSIZE); /* allocate buffer */
        ifp = fopen (argv[1], "r");  /* open file for reading */ 

        if (ifp && buffer) { /* if successful proceed */
            /* read file line by line */
            flag=0;
            while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, ifp) != NULL) {       
                /* defensive/secure programming */
                buflen = strlen(buffer);
                /* parse line */            
                z = strtok(buffer,sep);

                /* take in the values of the rows and columns */
                if(flag == 0){
                    ++flag;                 /* Flag = 1 */

                    Rows = atoi(z);         /* Convert the string to double */
                    printf("  %d",Rows);
                    z = strtok(NULL, sep);  /* find next number */
                    Columns = atoi(z);      /* Convert the string to double */           
                    printf("  %d",Columns);
                    putchar('\n');

                    A = m_alloc(Rows,Columns);
                    b = v_alloc(Rows);
                    x = v_alloc(Rows);
                    p = iv_alloc(Rows);

                    L = m_alloc(Rows,Columns);
                    U = m_alloc(Rows,Columns);
                }
                /* take in the values of the matrices */
                else{

                    for(int i = 0; i < Rows; i++){
                        A->mat[CurrentRow][i] = (Real) atof(z);             /* Convert the string to an int*/
                        z = strtok(NULL, sep);  /* find next number */
                        printf("   %2.3f   ",A->mat[CurrentRow][i]);
                    }

                    b->vec[CurrentRow] = (Real) atof(z);            /* Convert the string to an int */
                    printf("   %2.3f   ",b->vec[CurrentRow]);           
                    putchar('\n');
                    CurrentRow++;
                    putchar('\n');
                }

            } 
            fclose (ifp); 

...
```

I didn't print the rest of my code because I just do not see it as relevant to the question at hand. I want to know why this problem is occurring and how I could fix it in code, because I will need the information to solve for Ax=b later on in the program. The text file gives me the augmented matrix [A|b] and so I solve for x using LU factorization. I think it might have to do with the buffer itself, but I'm also inexperienced with C programming.

Also the text file I am reading is written as such...

```
 3 4
 2 1 1  1
 6 2 1 -7
-2 2 1  7
```

These are the results I get from the code

```
  3  4
   2.000      1.000      1.000      1.000

   6.000      2.000      1.000      -7.000

   -2.000      2.000      1.000      7.000

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thank you for your time. :)

UPDATE: I tried running gdb to debug and I've been stuck on trying to run the core dump with a text file. (ex. ./hw6 ge1.txt is what I would type into the command line). How do I run this with the text file, because it is segfaulting without it.

```
 c
Continuing.
Expecting two or three arguments
The second argument must be a text file to read from.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a4e in m_free (M=0x0) at apmatrix.c:32
32              free(M->mat[0]); /* free data */
```

Comment: Hook GDB and try finding the line causing crash?

Comment: Infinite loop or segmentation fault? You can't really have both problems.

Comment: `z = strtok(NULL, sep);  Columns = atoi(z);` does not check if `z === NULL`.

Comment: Try to verify if buflen is 0! If it's 0 you don't execute the string parsing, (I think you may break the while, but I'm not sure it's correct! But if you see that the program remains in loop after buflen becomes 0, then to break the while is the right way).

Answer (score 0):

```
1) compile your program with -ggdb parameter
2) link your program with the -ggdb parameter
```

This will result in a executable that contains the max amount of debug information, usable by the gdb debugger.

```
3) assure the source code is visible from where the program is to be run
   (in the same directory works very well)
4) at the command line: gdb yourProgramName
5) from within gdb enter the following commands
    br main    <-- sets breakpoint at main
    run        <-- execution program until breakpoint reached
    c          <-- continue execution
6) when the program crashes, enter the following commands
   bt          <-- display a back trace
7) examine the back trace to see which line your program crashed on.

8) quit y      <-- to exit the program
9) let us know which line that is.  
   paste/edit the line into your question
   as a line number would be meaningless to us.
```